# Can't get the children of root element in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml file, structured like this:

```
<textureatlas xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" imagepath="someImage.png">
  <subtexture name="1" x="342" y="0" width="173" height="171"></subtexture>
  <subtexture name="2" x="0" y="346" width="169" height="173"></subtexture>
  <subtexture name="3" x="0" y="173" width="169" height="173"></subtexture>
  <subtexture name="4" x="0" y="0" width="169" height="173"></subtexture>
  <subtexture name="5" x="342" y="171" width="169" height="173"></subtexture>
  <subtexture name="6" x="169" y="0" width="173" height="171"></subtexture>
  <subtexture name="7" x="169" y="173" width="173" height="171"></subtexture>
  <subtexture name="8" x="169" y="346" width="173" height="171"></subtexture>
  <subtexture name="9" x="342" y="346" width="173" height="171"></subtexture>
</textureatlas>
```

And I want to iterate through every `subtexture` element, using `Linq` in `C#`. However, my code doesn't work:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(pathToXml);
var root = document.Root;

if (root == null)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

var subtextureElements =
    from element in root.Elements("subtexture")
    select element;

foreach (var element in subtextureElements)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("okay");
}
```

The Debugger doesn't print anything. And when I add a breakpoint, I see that `subtextureElements` is empty. What am I doing wrong? I searched the internet and the approach with `root.Elements("subtextures)` isn't working either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This call

```
root.Elements("subtexture")
```

asks for elements called `subtexture` with no namespace. Due to *namespace defaulting* with the `xmlns=...` attribute, they're actually in the namespace with the URI `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. Fortunately LINQ to XML makes it really easy to use namespaces, using the implicit conversion from `string` to `XNamespace`, and then the `+` operator to combine a namespace with an element name to create an `XName`:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
var subtextureElements = root.Elements(ns + "subtexture");
```

(There's no benefit in using a query expression here, by way. I *suspect* `XDocument.Root` will never be null for a document loaded with `XDocument.Load`, either.)

Comment: Oh, dang it. I would've never suspected that attribute :D (the xml file is generated by an online tool). Thank you!  I'll accept the answer once I can (Yeah, I'll remove the query and use the Elements() approach. I just tried multiple things, because it didn't work)